# Flutter TikTokStyleFullPageScroller() not working on empty (non content) screen

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and trying to add slide functions to videos. It seems to be working as expected but only if slide by tapping on content area. In other words if tapped on video to slide it doesn't work.

Package:

```
tiktoklikescroller: ^0.1.1

import 'package:tiktoklikescroller/tiktoklikescroller.dart';
```

Here is my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final List<Color> colors = <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.blue, Colors.yellow];
  return Expanded(
    child: TikTokStyleFullPageScroller(
      contentSize: colors.length,
      swipeThreshold: 0.2,
      swipeVelocityThreshold: 2000,
      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            VideoDescription(),
            ActionToolbar(),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Video Description

```
class VideoDescription extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        child: Container(
          height: 70.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 160.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Title', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Action Toolbar

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100.0,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          _getMusicPlayerAction(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Please help.

Comment: Please mention full detail. Which package you are using?

Comment: Thanks @Yash, please have a look at updated question.

Comment: Could you share me `VideoDescription()` and `ActionToolbar()`. This way I could help more.

Comment: Okay it's there now.

Comment: As far, I have Discovered you have remove Expanded widget above `TikTokStyleFullPageScroller` and next you need pass correct and relevant `contentSize`. as you are not using `List<Color> colors` but still using its length.

Comment: This seems to be a package issue. I suggest you to open a issue on the package github repository.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Yash and @ Vipin malik, I think I figured it out. I wrapped `VideoDescription()` and `ActionToolbar()` inside a container and gave it a transparent color. I will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped VideoDescription() and ActionToolbar() inside a container and gave it a transparent color.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final List<Color> colors = <Color>[Colors.red, 
Colors.blue, Colors.yellow];
  return Expanded(
child: TikTokStyleFullPageScroller(
  contentSize: colors.length,
  swipeThreshold: 0.2,
  swipeVelocityThreshold: 2000,
  animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        VideoDescription(),
        ActionToolbar(),
      ],
     ),
    );
  },
    ),
  );
}
```